# I lost my password on lucidworks 1.7

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, solr

I have installed lucidworks-enterprise-installer-1.7 on my ubuntu server at /etc/solr
it is working fine. but when i go to

```
http://XXX.YY.ZZZ.VV:8989/login
```

i can't login using the default username/password (admin/admin)... it seems i have changed it although i dont remember that i did so.
i have done this:  `vim /etc/solr/conf/lwe-core/users.yml` and the content was as below!! i couldn't be able to change it :(

```
!!com.lucid.admin.users.User {createDate: &id001 !!timestamp '2011-08-01T08:19:57.744Z',
  email: alaa@mydomain.com, firstName: Alaa, id: -1, lastModified: *id001, lastName: Alomari,
  password: $2a$10$FIskfU9M8Z4.62.VAx2Xl.Q4/Hkbq0XTCNBmDxT1P1jMfGisQGDMC, username: admin}
```

if anybody knows how to reset the password, please guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The hash in the password field looks like a crypt-entry to me.

Try to run the following command

```
perl -e 'print crypt("mynewpassword", "\$1\$mynewsalt"), "\n";'
```

And replace the contents of the password field with the new content.

Remember to back up the old file first.

Comment: unfortunately .. this didn't work... also i am not sure if this file contains the user/pass